# How do I test the function call made by the method to other methods

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma and jasmine for unit testing. How do I test the function call made by the method to other methods? Do I use Spies in jasmine?

**Ticket.controller.controller.js**

```
function hello()
 {
    test();
    test1();
}
```

**Ticketcontroller.controller.test.js(test file)**

```
describe('checks hello',function(){

 beforeEach(inject(_$controller_){
  var controller=_$controller_;
    };

 it('the spec',function(){

   spyOn(controller,'test')l
   expect(controller.test).toHaveBeenCalled();

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply watch and call through them:

```
spyOn(controller,'test').and.callThrough();
spyOn(controller,'test1').and.callThrough();

controller.hello();

expect(controller.test).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(controller.test1).toHaveBeenCalled();
```